# Select2 with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2

How can I use select2 with AngularJS to load (in addition to the default values​​), others user's input. 
I allow people to type values into the text box.
Below is the code I am trying to fix:

```
$scope.options = [
                   {id:'0', value:'nessuno'},
                   {id:'1', value:'prova'}
                 ];

self.optionsSelect2Query = function(query){
     var results = [];

     results.push({id: query.term, text: query.term});
     _.each(self.options(), function (item) {
         results.push({
             id: item.name,
             value: item.value
         })
     });

     query.callback({ results: results });
 }

<select class="form-control" ui-select2="optionsSelect2Query" ng-model="selectedOption" ></select>
```

Comment: post the code you have been working on!